# How to always apply quotes (escape) in Super CSV

Tags: csv, supercsv

i would like to put my file csv like this forma:

> "User 2";"Web Page" ;"AbdelMonem NAAMANE";;;;

i make my own Csv Preference like that:

> private static final CsvPreference myPreference = new
>   CsvPreference.Builder('"',';''\n').build();

i would like to have a header like that `"User 2";"Web Page"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to see what you're doing without a complete code example, but from your [post](http://sourceforge.net/p/supercsv/bugs/50/) on the Super CSV bug tracker, I suspect that you're asking how to *always quote* CSV fields.

There's extensive documentation on the [Super CSV website](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/preferences.html) on how to configure custom preferences - the feature you're after is the *quote mode*.

Here's an example of using the `AlwaysQuote` quote mode, which quotes every field even if it doesn't contain special characters.

```
CsvPreference prefs = new CsvPreference.Builder('"',';',"\n")
    .useQuoteMode(new AlwaysQuoteMode()).build();

ICsvListWriter writer = new CsvListWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out), 
    prefs);
writer.writeHeader("User2", "Web Page");
writer.flush();
```

Which prints:

```
"User2";"Web Page"
```