# How can I tell SuperCSV NOT to map empty string to null

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

I am using ICsvListReader and ICsvListWriter to read and write csv file.
**I found that the empty string in csv file is converted to null and then output.**
How can I avoid this happen. I've tried create a new CellProcessor:

```
private CellProcessor[] getProcessors(int columnNumber){

        CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[columnNumber];
        for (int i=0; i< columnNumber; i++){
            processors[i] = new ConvertNullTo("");
        }
        return processors;
    }
```

But it still not working.

Is there any way to change this setting?

Answer (score 0):

Empty columns don't require escaping in CSV (so by default Super CSV won't apply quotes around empty strings), but if you want quotes to always be applied then you can change the [QuoteMode](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/preferences.html) in Super CSV.

Here's a [recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21470209/1068649) on SO that demonstrates this.

*Update:* If you only want to quote empty strings, then make sure the values you're writing are empty String (i.e. you may need to use `ConvertNullTo("")`), then use the following quote mode:

```
public class QuoteEmptyString implements QuoteMode {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean quotesRequired(String csvColumn, CsvContext context, 
        CsvPreference preference) {
        return "".equals(csvColumn);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but I dont want quotes to always be applied, just on empty string,